# ajax call php code in a file and get result

Tags: php, ajax

Some code I want to call from ajax is in a separate file.php:

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
    //some code here processing $email1
     $response = 'some text';
?>
```

This is how I call it from ajax:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'file.php',
    data: {email1: $("#user_email").val()},
    type: 'post'
       });
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this after the call to file.php:

```
 alert($response);
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP you have to echo the `$response`, and in your JS you have to specify the callback function like so:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'file.php',
    data: {
        email1: $("#user_email").val()
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) { 
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! What I was missing at first was echoing the $response.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the ajax call, include a success.. ex:

```
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
```

This will pop an alert up with your response.

Comment: In addition a would suggest to add `header( "Content-Type: text/html" );` to the `.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'file.php',
    data: {email1: $("#user_email").val()},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) { 
          alert(data);
    }
 });
```

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You also need to `echo` out the response in your PHP file:

```
echo $response;
```

Comment: He also has to echo the `$response` first.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: {email1: $("#user_email").val()},
  success: function(data) {
      alert(data); 
  }
});
```